# Probability measure on $(\mathbb N _0,2^{\mathbb N_0})$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

We denote by $\mathbb N _0$ the set of all nonnegative integers,$\mathbb N$ the set of all positive integers.

Fix $\epsilon$＞0,can we choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu(\{ N+1,N+2,... \}) \lt \epsilon$?

Does there exist an $\epsilon$ together with some probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb N _0,2^{\mathbb N _0})$ such that $\mu(\{ 0,1,...,N \}) \lt 1 - \epsilon$ but $\mu (\mathbb N _0)$=1?

I think we cannot merely identify $\mu (\mathbb N _0)$ with $\lim_{N \to \infty} \mu ( \{ 0,1,...,N \} )$,therefore I guess there may exist some probability measure $\mu$ that fulfills $\mu (\{ 0,1,...,N \}) \lt 1 - \epsilon $ for some appropriate $\epsilon$ and all $N \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: You can define $\mu(\{n\})=1/2^n$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have just corrected some typos :)

Comment: Well, my answer is still true :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have $$\mu(\mathbb{N_0}) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \mu(\{0,1,\ldots,N\})$$ as a property of measures.  In particular, for a finite measure, we always have $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \mu(\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n > N\}) = 0$$

---

Using the above, we can conclude

> Fix $\epsilon$＞0,can we choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu(\{ N+1,N+2,... \}) \lt \epsilon$?

Yes, by the second limit and the fact every probability measure is finite.

> Does there exist an $\epsilon$ together with some probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb N _0,2^{\mathbb N _0})$ such that $\mu(\{ 0,1,...,N \}) \lt 1 - \epsilon$ but $\mu (\mathbb N _0)$=1?

If $N$ is dependent on $\epsilon,$ then the answer is yes.  If $N$ is independent of $\epsilon,$ then no, by the first limit.

Comment: … and such measures exist. End of story.

Comment: @k.stm I'm sorry,the existences of what?